# shortest path algorithm recursion

Tags: python, recursion, shortest-path

As a programing exercise, I am trying to solve a puzzle game in Python.  For this I'm using a recursive algorithm, which I thought to be a depth-first-search implementation.  My problem is that I get a runtime error for reaching the maximum recursion limit, and I haven't figured out how to solve it.

I have seen different posts about both the game and the algorithm, but rather than recoding it in this setting, I was hoping to get helpful insight about what I have written. 
So here's a pseudo-simplified version of my code.

```
# Keep track of paths that I have found for given states. 
best_paths = dict()

def find_path(state, previous_states = set()):

  # The output is a tuple of the length of the path and the path.
  if state in previous_states:
    return (infty,None)
  previous_states = copy and update with state

  if state in target_states: 
    best_paths[state] = (0,[])

  if state in best_paths:
    return best_paths[state]

  possible_moves = set((piece,spaces) that can be moved)
  (shortest_moves,shortest_path) = (infty,None)
  for (piece,spaces) in possible_moves:
    move_piece(piece,spaces)
    try_state = the resulting state after moving the piece
    (try_moves,try_path) = find_path(try_state,previous_states)

    if try_moves < shortest_moves:
      shortest_moves = try_moves + 1
      shortest_path  = try_path + [(piece,spaces)]

    # Undo the move for the next call
    move_piece(piece,-spaces)

  if shortest_moves < infty:
    best_paths[state] = shortest_path

  return (best_moves, shortest_path)
```

So my question is if having the return outside of the for loop what's causing the recursion to get to the maximum?
thank you for your help.

  -

Comment: there is a code-review site, this is a Q/A site.

Comment: python recursion doesnt let you go very deep ... may want to look at iterative solutions

Comment: The thing is that based on the problem, I shouldn't need to go very deep... and also, thanks for the code-review tip.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hitting the recursion depth exceeded exception, you either have a code problem or you need a different algorithm. It looks like you're algorithm is O(N*N) where N is the number of nodes. N doesn't need to be very large for you to hit the limit.

There are better approaches to the problem.